# What can be done with Rust's generic FromStr object?

Tags: rust

Rust's `str` class has a `parse` method that returns a `FromStr` object. `parse` is templated, and so the type that's being parsed from the `str` can be manually specified, e.g. `"3".parse::<i32>()` evaluates to (a `Result` object containing) the 32-bit int `3`.

But failing to specify the type does not seem to be an error in itself. Instead, I get an error when trying to print the resulting (generic/unspecified) `FromStr` object:

```
let foo = "3".parse();
match foo
{
    Ok(m) => println!("foo: {}", m),
    Err(e) => println!("error! {}", e)
}
```

This does **not** give an error on the first line; instead, I get the following error:

```
<anon>:24:12: 24:13 error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required [E0282]
<anon>:24         Ok(m) => println!("foo: {}", m),
```

(Here, line 24 is the line with the `Ok(m)`.)

So what is `m` here? Or is the "unable to infer enough type information" error actually due to the fact that `parse` in fact *can't* be called without a type specifier, and the compiler just doesn't catch the error until the first line where the resulting `Ok` type is actually used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Rust's `str` class has a `parse` method that returns a `FromStr` object.

Stop right here, this is your error.

`parse` does not return a `FromStr` object; `FromStr` is a `trait` which can be thought of as an **abstract class** if you come from an OO background, and you cannot return an object with an abstract type: it's abstract!

What `parse` does return, thus, is an instance of some type `T` which must implement the `FromStr` interface.

> But failing to specify the type does not seem to be an error in itself. Instead, I get an error when trying to print the resulting (generic/unspecified) `FromStr` object

Because there cannot be such generic/unspecific `FromStr` object. A concrete type must be inferred (from context) or explicitly spelled out, and this type must implement `FromStr`.

> So what is `m` here?

Only you know what it should be, the compiler does not, and thus complain that it does not know what to do :)

> Or is the "unable to infer enough type information" error actually due to the fact that parse in fact can't be called without a type specifier, and the compiler just doesn't catch the error until the first line where the resulting `Ok` type is actually used?

Basically.

Except that it's not so much that the compiler doesn't catch the error until the first line where the resulting `Ok` is used, and more that the compiler considers the full function at once when inferring types. From the point of view of the compiler, whether the actual clue to infer the type comes immediately or comes 50 lines down does not matter, it only needs to be present in the current function body.

It might lead to the complaint about the lack of type originating in an odd place from the developer point of view; this is one of the downfalls of type inference. On the other hand, the compiler just cannot know where YOU would prefer to put the annotation. There are after all many possibilities:

```
// Example 1: immediately specifying the type
fn main() {
    let foo = "3".parse::<i32>();
    match foo
    {
        Ok(m) => println!("foo: {}", m),
        Err(e) => println!("error! {}", e)
    }
}

// Example 2: partially specifying the result type
// Note: the "_" is deduced to be std::num::ParseIntError because
//       this is how `FromStr::Err` is defined for `i32`.
fn main() {
    let foo: Result<i32, _> = "3".parse();
    match foo
    {
        Ok(m) => println!("foo: {}", m),
        Err(e) => println!("error! {}", e)
    }
}

// Example 3: specifying the result type of unwrapping
fn doit() -> Result<(), std::num::ParseIntError> {
    let foo: i32 = try!("3".parse());
    println!("foo: {}", foo);
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    match doit()
    {
        Ok(_) => (),
        Err(e) => println!("error! {}", e)
    }
}

// Example 4: letting the type be inferred from a function call
fn callit(f: i32) {
    println!("f: {}", f);
}

fn main() {
    let foo = "3".parse();
    match foo
    {
        Ok(m) => callit(m),
        Err(e) => println!("error! {}", e)
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, though I'm still not quite clear on why the error occurs where it does, and what the full range of possibilities for annotating types is. For instance, I get what looks like a parse error (`expected one of...`) when I try to annotate the type within the `match` expression using `Ok(m: i32)`. All of your examples show modifications  to the statement *in which the parse occurs*, which doesn't demonstrate that "the compiler considers the full function at once when inferring types."

Comment: Additionally, if I comment everything out *except* the `parse` line, I *do* get an error indicating that the parse itself must have some kind of type-specification: `type annotations required: cannot resolve '<_ as core::str::FromStr>::Err == _'` ... so why doesn't this error show up in the original code?

Comment: @KyleStrand: I added a 4th example letting inference shine. Note how the type is no longer specified in the `parse` statement, but instead (1) the fact that `m` is `i32` is deduced from it being used in `callit(m)` where `callit` is `fn(i32) -> ()`, (2) as a result the type of `foo` is deduced to be `Result<i32, <i32 as FromStr>::Err>` and (3) as a result the type of `e` is deduced to be `<i32 as FromStr>::Err>` otherwise known as `std::num::ParseIntError`. As for getting the error in the `parse` statement if it's the only thing you have... well, the error will always appear in code you write.

Comment: The new example helps. Is it possible to do the annotation explicitly at the point of usage without a function call, though? Also, I'm not confused about why I *do* get an error when the only line is the parse statement, I'm confused about why I *don't* get the same error in the original code, in addition to the error for the line where the "Ok" case is actually used.

Comment: @KyleStrand: *Is it possible to do the annotation explicitly at the point of usage without a function call, though?* => I only know of "rebinding" (ie `let foo: i32 = foo;`) which cannot be used within an expression. As for the placement of errors... I don't know whether it's taste or fate. Taste: the type is only necessary from this point on, so it's flagged here; Fate: it just so happens to be the point where the error is detected, and nobody spent any particular effort to move it elsewhere (maybe because like me they find it clear enough).

Answer (score 2):

It's just not clear what m is here, as there isn't enough information to say. Is it an i32? A u64? Nobody, including Rust, can know.

You need to do something to help figure out what type it is. Either pass it to a function expecting a specific type, or annotate it such that it can be determined what type it should be.

Comment: It might be worth noting that there's no "`FromStr` object" at all.  There is merely a value of some type which *implements* `FromStr` (though what that type is, the compiler can't know).