# Cannot infer type when using map over a split of strings

Tags: rust

I'm currently trying to learn Rust by doing Advent of Code. I have as input a file containing integers (one per line). I now try to parse that file using the following code:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut file = File::open("./input/day1_input.txt")?;
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents)?;
    let split = contents.split("\n").map(|x| x.parse().unwrap());
    for x in split {
        println!("{}",x);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

I get a compiler error on split in the for-loop with the error message: "cannot infer type". Can someone please explain me why I get this message and what would be the proper way to do this? Other hints how this parsing can be done more efficient are welcome but not the primary reason for the question.

Comment: I'd recommend to add appropriate tags, when you post a question. This will engage people subscribed to that tag and it'll disengage people unsubscribed from it.

Comment: Compiler doesn't know which particular number type you're parsing. Try `parse::<u32>()` or any other

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklaurij it's a basic rust question - what other tags to you expect?

Comment: @AlexLarionov please post it as answer and I can accept it. That was what I was missing. Thank you.

Comment: Rust Expert™ tip #1: use [`std::fs::read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_to_string.html) instead of `File::open` + `read_to_string`; it's more concise and, probably, more efficient.

Comment: Rust Expert™ tip #2: use [`contents.lines()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines) instead of `contents.split("\n")`: it works for Windows-formatted text files and correctly handles files that end with newlines (i.e. most files).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can be done with Rust's generic FromStr object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687388/what-can-be-done-with-rusts-generic-fromstr-object) I think Matthieu's answer covers everything you might need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler doesn't know which particular number type you're parsing. Try `parse::<u32>()` or any other.

As a file reading suggestion, beware of large files, since you read the whole file in a single `String`. Since every memory inside of a `String`has to be contiguous, it may happen that there's no contiguous block of memory sufficient for the whole file's content. So instead you better wrap your `File` in a `BufReader` so that you can request some part of content without worrying about making many extremely expensive operating system calls. And then you  read the content in pieces of controllable size, say lines or chunks of a few megabytes.